# Input border change when background image is added

Tags: html, css

When I add background image to an input, its border changed too.

[image]

So now my button looks different from other.

How can I make them look the same?

Here is the JsFriddle for this problem

http://jsfiddle.net/apLm5rgq/1/

But basically it is

```
<input id='one'  value='One'/>
<br/>
<input id='two'  value='Two'/>
```

and

```css
input {
    text-align: right
}
#two {
    background-image:  url(http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/tips-and-tricks/input-with-background/images/magnifying-glass.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks you all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To maintain the default input style, set the `border-width` and `border-style` for the inputs explicitly. This works in Chrome and IE - in Firefox it changes the border color slightly from default, but the style is consistent across all text inputs. This gets you 90% of the result you want.

**Updated**  - [Have a basic fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/nycgdkrb/10)

```
input {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset outset outset inset; 
    /* 
     Seems to be most browsers default (tested on Windows)
    */
}
```

The [documentation over on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) may be useful to you.

---

You can also set your own border on inputs for a consistent look across browsers and operating systems.

[Have a nicer fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/nycgdkrb/2/)

```
input {
    text-align: right;
    border: solid 1px #ADA9A5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Also, position your background with `background-position` to compensate for the inputs padding.

```
#two {
    background-position: 5px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ohh i got that, its for the image. Great Solution.

Comment: Yes, the padding will cause the background image to display in the top left corner and look weird. The `background-position` corrects this :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. The solution you suggest DOES work and I really appreciate that. However, I don't quite like the idea that I redefine what should be the default border of inputs. The default border setting of each browser should match with default border of components.

Comment: @NawaMan - I have updated my answer with the closest I have been so far to maintaining default browser styles whilst also fixing that annoying 2px margin on the input with the background.